# Encoding a feature in Dataframe (both Numerical and Non Numerical)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, outliers

I want to Encode a feature that contains both Non-Numerical and Numerical Information. This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
dictionary = {'Values':['Y','N','Y','N',99,'N'],'AGE':[23,24,12,-99,778,13]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index = range(1,len(dictionary['Values'])+1))

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
columns = df.columns.tolist()
for i in columns:
    if(df[i].dtype == 'object'):
        df[i] = encoder.fit_transform(df[i])
df
```

My expected output is:

```
    Values  AGE
1   1       23
2   0       24
3   1       12
4   0       -99
5   99      778
6   0       13
```

But I am getting error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'".

Any advises how to rectify this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelEncoder()` uses a `sort()` function, which is incompatible with multiclass variables (it cannot compare strings to integers - how can you tell if `'a'` is bigger or smaller than `1`?). You could disregard the integers in your dataset and only fit-transform on the rows that have strings as `Values`:

```
dictionary = {'Values':['Y','N','Y','N',99,'N'],'AGE':[23,24,12,-99,778,13]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index = range(1,len(dictionary['Values'])+1))

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
columns = df.columns.tolist()

mask = df['Values'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))
df['Values'][mask] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Values'][mask])

df
```

(Just a question - why do you need `if(df[i].dtype == 'object')` and that whole for loop? I couldn't figure it out why you're looping through the columns if you only want to encode the first one.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to encode all the features that consists of string (objects) inside them.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to remove the outliers and Inconsistent values. could you please suggest me some ideas for these

Comment: @JSabariVishnuJayanthan This will encode all rows where strings are in the `Values` column. If you have additional questions, please post them separately!